# Specify language for response in Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm using the Google Cloud Vision API to detect landmarks, webEntities and other things from a given image (check the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries)), I am specifically using the images:annotate endpoint, and I want to specify the language, I want the returned results to be in English.

Is there a way I can achieve that?

Comment: Are you talking about translating non-English text to English or something else? Additional specify how you are connecting to the API - Firebase SDK, HTTP API, gRPC API, etc.

Comment: No, I'm talking about specifying the language in which the responses need to be returned, for example in maps APIs you can specify the language and if you search for "louvre" and you specify English the name returned is "Louvre Museum" if Spanish the returned name is "Museo de Louvre"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this document](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels) states that the only language for retrieved labels is English and you can use `Cloud Translation API` to translate it into other language. About specifying language in Vision API, as far as I know, one can give language hint for `TEXT_DETECTION` as explained in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1p2beta1/ImageContext) but I'm not aware to specify language in non-text detection.

Answer (score 7):

Add the `image_context` into the response and you should be all set.

```
response = client.text_detection(
    image=image,
    image_context={"language_hints": ["bn"]},  # Bengali
)
```

Comment: This only works for text_detection (OCR).  For the other Vision features, which is what the OP was asking about, it has no effect on the labels returned

Comment: Confirmed, this parameter does improve detection results a bit!